# Error star server the react

Tags: reactjs

estuve creando mi app con react y al momento de iniciar el servidor me sale el error que se muestra en la imagen y no se a que se debe,agradeceria mucho si me ayudara, muchas gracias de antemano
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]